# Implicit conversion from object to integer and other errors

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2017

I have two Layes Classes Business Layer And Data Layer And i have The Main class i called DatabaseManager contain all functions i need for stored procedures

```
I search on these errors I cannot find solutions
```

First Error in DatabaseManager class is :

**implicit conversion from object to integer**

```
Public Function ExecuteScalar(ByVal sql As String) As Object
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql) With {
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
            .Connection = Connection
        }
        Dim retval As Integer = ExecuteScalar(cmd)
        Return retval
End Function
```

**In Data Layer Class i have this code :**

```
Friend Function Get_Last_Visits_Type(ByRef cmd As SqlCommand)
            Dim retval As Integer
            cmd = New SqlCommand("Get_Last_Visits_Type")
            retval = dm.ExecuteScalar(cmd)
            Return retval
End Function
```

I got two errors here

**function without an 'as' clause return type of object assumed**

**And**

**implicit conversion from object to integer**

When Form Loaded i put this code on Load action :

```
TxtVisitTypeID.Text = Val(p.Get_Last_Visits_Type)
```

And i got this error :

**implicit conversion from Double to String**

Thanks...

Comment: Did you paste and edit some pieces of code here? What is this: `Dim retval As Integer = ExecuteScalar(cmd)` supposed to do? Recursive calls to itself? Maybe you wanted `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead? This returns an Object, that's probably why your function is meant to return an Object type. The second method doesn't have a return Type declared. Not really clear why you have `ByRef` there and why you're passing a `SqlCommand` to `ExecuteScalar()` which is expecting a string instead. Do you have `Option Strict On`. No? That's the first thing you do when you install Visual Studio.

Comment: You should ALWAYS specify the return type of a function and you MUST do so with `Option Strict On`, which it should always be. If you do specify the return type, why would you declare it as `Object` when you know for a fact that the actual value returned will be an `Integer`? You need to put more thought into your data types and `Option Strict On` forces you to do that. For example, `Val` returns a `Double` and the `Text` of a control is type `String`, so it should be obvious that you need to convert that `Double` to a `String`.

Comment: I would vote to close this question because it contains several questions. Each should be addressed in a separate question. I hesitate to do so because there is already so much good help provided by @SteveCinq in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few problems here as mentioned in comments:

1. Avoid naming a function anything that is a reserved word in the scope of your project at the very least: `ExecuteScalar` is a method of `SqlCommand` so use something like `MyExecuteScalar` instead.
2. `Dim retval As Integer = ExecuteScalar(cmd)` probably should be `Dim retval As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()` unless you want a recursion (which I doubt). (Refer 1.)
3. Turn `Option Strict` *on* in your project settings. As mentioned, ALWAYS have this on. (And I prefer to have `Option Explicit` *on* and `Option Infer` *off* as well for similar reasons.)
4. With compile options set as in 3. you will have (valid) compilation errors pertaining to type conversion (at least), with a good chance of resulting in working code once you fix them. Eg `Dim retval As Integer = Ctype(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)` (if you're sure that the result of the query will be `Integer`, otherwise you will need to test and/or error trap).
5. `Connection` isn't defined anywhere: `.Connection = Connection`. You don't pass it nor declare it.
6. Since `retval` is declared as an `Integer` then the return type can also be tightened up to `Integer` as well, rather than `Object`.
7. Your second function has no return type.
8. What is `dm`? Not declared/defined.
9. Consider using `Using` blocks to close-and-dispose of SQL connection and command on exit.
10. `CommandType.Text` is the default so you only need to state it by way of explanation.

Here's what I'd do with your first function:

```
Public Function MyExecuteScalar(ByVal sql As String) As Integer
    Try
        Using con As New SqlConnection(sql)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
                Return CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch
        Return -1 ' Or something recognizable as invalid, or simply Throw
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: If you are just going Throw then don't even implement exception handling. Let the exception bubble up to the calling code or where ever you intend to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing the first function:

This code is too abstract to be useful. The name of the function is bad. It appears to be recursive but the value you pass back to the function is not a string but a command. If the line of code is `Dim retval As Integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()`, then .ExecuteScalar() returns an Object. You cannot convert an Object to an Integer without a conversion method. If you are declaring retval as an Integer why would you have typed your function As Object? I won't even get into the connection problem here. I suggest you delete the function and start again.

Addressing the second function:

Why are you passing the command ByRef? This function has no connection at all! How do you expect it to execute anything? Same problem with retval As Integer and ExecuteScalar returning an Object.
Again, delete and start again.

Now to the code in Form.Load:

Val went out with VB6. I can give unanticipated results. Guess what, Val returns a Double. A .Text property expects a string. Also you appear to be calling the function you showed us above. That function asks for the calling code to provide an argument, namely an SqlCommand object.

My suggestions:

Forget about layers and try to learn the basics of data access with ADO.net. Turn on Option Strict now and forever. Ask new questions with a single problem. Tell us what line the error occurs on. You have been advised before that functions require a datatype but it doesn't seem to sink in.